# Holomorphic sections to anti-holomorphic sections

Tags: complex-geometry, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold and $L$ be a holomorphic line bundle on $X$ with a Hermitian metric $h$. I am trying to give a norm preserving isomorphism between the space of holomorphic sections of $L$ and the space of anti-holomorphic sections of $L^*$. Now let's say $\phi$ be a nontrivial holomorphic section on $L$, we define
\begin{align*}
\Gamma(X;L)\rightarrow \Gamma(X;L^*)\\
\phi\mapsto \phi^*; \phi^*(\alpha)=h(\alpha,\phi)\\
\end{align*}
This map is complex anti-linear and we define $\langle\phi^*,\psi^*\rangle_{h^*}:=\langle\psi,\phi\rangle_{h}.$ Does this map take a holomorphic section to an anti-holomorphic section or we need to make the map complex-linear? How do I check if the described section $\phi^*$ is holomorphic or anti-holomorphic?

**Edit:** The above question arises to me while reading about Seiberg-Witten theory on Kähler surfaces. I am attaching two instances where the following language is used which led me trying to understand it properly. The first one is from John Morgan's book:[The Seiberg–Witten equations and applications to the topology of smooth four manifolds](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691025971/the-seiberg-witten-equations-and-applications-to-the-topology-of) (page 113)

[image: cap 1]

and the second one is from Liviu Nicolaescu's [Notes on Seiberg-Witten Theory](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/swnotes.pdf) (page 232).

[image: cap 2]

Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Whether you take the linear or anti-linear version, this is definitely false. The metric is $C^{\infty}$, not holomorphic. In fact, if $L$ is nontrivial and has a nonzero holomorphic section, $L^*$ has no nonzero holomorphic (or anti-holomorphic) section.

Comment: @abx, I undestand $L^*$ doesn't have holo section because of degree reason, but why can't it have an anti-holo section?

Comment: Actually I don't know what is an anti-holomorphic section of a holomorphic line bundle.

Comment: @abx, one definition would be, if you put a Chern connection $A$ w.r.t the hermitian metric $h,$ then $\partial_A(\alpha)=0$. I believe this should be equivalent to having local anti-holo functions, $s_u$ such that $s_u=g_{uv}s_v,$ $g_{uv}$ being the holo transition functions of the line bundle.

Comment: If $s_u$ and $s_v$ are anti-holomorphic, $g_{uv}$ is anti-holomorphic...  I will stop the discussion, perhaps you should think more about what you want to ask.

Comment: @abx, sorry the equivalent idea was very wrong. I'll try to update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me attempt an answer:

First, we see our holomorphic line bundle as a smooth complex line bundle $L$ together with a $\bar \partial$-operator $\bar \partial_L$ that is integrable (i.e. $\bar \partial_L\wedge \bar \partial_L = 0$).

Let us now endow $L$ with a Hermitian metric $h$. Then the Chern connection of $h$ takes the form $\partial_L +\bar \partial_L$ where $\partial_L$ is an integrable $\partial$-operator. This operator defines a holomorphic structure on the complex line bundle $\bar L$ (i.e. $L$ with the opposite complex structure in the fibers). This holomorphic structure depends on $h$ and is not canonical at all.

Now, $\bar \partial_L$ and $\partial_L$ also induce holomorphic structures on $L^*$ and $\bar L^*$ respectively. Let me denote $\bar \partial_{L^*}$ and $\partial_{L^*}$ the corresponding operators.

Finally, by construction of the Chern connection, the metric $h$ define a holomorphic isomorphism between $(\bar L, \partial_L)$ and $(L^*, \bar \partial_{L^*})$ and a holomorphic isomorphism between $(L, \bar \partial_L)$ and $({\bar L}^*, \partial_{L^*})$.

This last isomorphism sends a holomorphic section of $L$ to a section of $L^*$ satisfying $\partial_{L^*} s = 0$.

You could call that a "anti-holomorphic section" if you want (and it seems that the references you give do that) but it is a bit misleading because:

- the "anti-holomorphic structure" (i.e. the holomorphic structure on $\bar L$) is not canonically associated to the holomorphic structure (it depends on the choice of $h$)
- anti-holomorphic sections in that sense are not anti-holomorphic functions in local holomorphic coordinates (as pointed out by @abx in the comments, this does not even make sense).

There is a situation where this would make more sense: if your Chern connection is flat, then anti-holomorphic sections of $L$ or $L^*$ (in the sense $\partial s= 0$) are the sections which are locally anti-holomorphic functions in local *flat* coordinates.